# Linking Google Sheets with PostGIS

Tags: postgis, google-sheets

I am curious if there is a way to link a PostGIS table with a Google Sheets?

Both tables (Post and Google) have a unique ID that can be used as a linkage.  I am hoping to be able to build a view that will display information from both tables into a single view.

Comment: Does Google Sheets API (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/?hl=en) help?